# Optimize single word base form extraction (lemmatization) in spacy

Tags: spacy, lemmatization

I am looking to reduce a word to its base form without using contextual information. I tried out spacy and that requires running out nlp to get the base form of a single word but that comes with an increase in execution time.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636002/spacy-lemmatization-of-a-single-word) post where disabling parser and NER pipeline components speed up the execution time to some extent but I just want a process to directly lookup into the database of word and its lemma form ( basically the base form of a word without considering contextual information

```
my_list = ["doing", "done", "did", "do"]
for my_word in my_list:
    doc = nlp(my_word, disable=['parser', 'ner'])
    for w in doc:
        print("my_word {}, base_form {}".format(w, w.lemma_))
```

## desired output

```
my_word doing, base_form do
my_word done, base_form do
my_word did, base_form do
my_word do, base_form do
```

Note: I also tried out spacy.lemmatizer but that is not giving the expected results and required pos as an additional arugments.

Comment: Lemmatization is what you actually need to get the root word but Lemmatization for any NLP libraries is bit expensive , in the sense that it needs to lookup a dictionary for getting a lemmatized word for a given word .
therefore, if you pass list of word of n size , it first need to find its appropriate POS tag then lookup the dictionary with both word,POS tag all together.
Here is sample code for OpenNLP if you are interested how lemmatization is done(same strategy for NLTK etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want lemmas from a lookup table, you can install the lookup tables and initialize a very basic pipeline that only includes a tokenizer. If the lookup tables are installed, `token.lemma_` will look up the form in the table.

Install the lookup tables (which are otherwise only saved in the provided models and not included in the main `spacy` package to save space):

```
pip install spacy[lookups]
```

Tokenize and lemmatize:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
assert nlp("doing")[0].lemma_ == "do"
assert nlp("done")[0].lemma_ == "do"
```

Answer (score 0):

Spacy's lookup tables are available in this repository:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-lookups-data

There you can read the documentation and check the examples that might help you.